# How to convert string to number in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a const inherited from another component that looking at its typeof, is a string.
In javascript my code looks like this:

Here I display a number, eg 24%

```
{parseInt(progression * 100, 10)}%
```

Here I display a progress bar

```
<Bar style={{ width: `${progression * 100}%` }} />
```

I'm trying to change this code now to typescript and I did the following:

I declared the typing:

```
interface ProgressionProps {
  progression: string;
}
```

Here where I should display the %, I put it like this:

```
{Number(progression * 100, 10)}%
```

But I have the error:

> The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any',
> 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.ts

And also in the other code:

```
<Bar style={{ width: `${progression * 100}%` }} />
```

I got the same error:

> The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any',
> 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.ts

What am I doing wrong? What is the way to pass this code correctly to typescript?

Thanks if can someone help me!!

Comment: You can't operate on a string safely, so you have to convert *it and only it* to a string first: `Number(progression)`.

Comment: To explain Kelly's comment in a different way, when you do `progression * 100` you're trying to multiply a string by 100 and that's what Typescript is warning you about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to parse the string to a number **before** you multiply it:

```
{Number(progression) * 100}%
```

And

```
<Bar style={{ width: `${Number(progression) * 100}%` }} />
```

Comment: Thanks! Now, with `{Number(progression, 10) * 100}%` I got this: `Expected 0-1 arguments, but got 2.ts`

Comment: Right, just Number(....) Without the ,10